# Is public usage of private typedef portable?

Tags: c++, typedef

```
class Settings
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, SettingsOption> OptionMap;

public:
    typedef OptionMap::iterator iterator;
    typedef OptionMap::const_iterator const_iterator;

    ...
};
```

Is this code portable? What does the standard state about it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's legal and `Settings::iterator` and `Settings::const_iterator` are accessible to all users of the `Settings` class.

Access control in C++ is applied purely to names. There's a note and example in ISO/IEC 14882:2011 11 [class.access]/4 that makes it clear that this is the intention.

> [...] [ *Note:* Because access control applies to names, if access control is
>   applied to a typedef name, only the accessibility of the typedef name itself is considered. The accessibility
>   of the entity referred to by the typedef is not considered. For example,

```
class A {
  class B { };
public:
  typedef B BB;
};

void f() {
  A::BB x; // OK, typedef name A::BB is public
  A::B y; // access error, A::B is private
}
```

> —*end note* ]